# Search bar to find existing strings with <span id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a website that generates 100 Names, such as Joey, Daniel, Ronnie, etc. They're not generated from a database, and are like `<div class="names">Joey</div>` and such.

I have a Search bar  `<input type="text" id="Search" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="placeholder text" autofocus>`

How can I make it functional so whenever someone types a name out of the 100 Names, it will find it? And if the entered name isn't in 1 of the 100 Names, say "No results"

Comment: Ids have to be **unique** (`<div id="names" ...`). Use a class instead (`<div class="name" ...`).

Comment: @Andreas Thanks

Comment: Try looking at the the `autocomplete` UI from jquery (https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the [data-* attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*%20%22%22) whenever you need to work with data from the DOM in javascript.

Your elements with names should look like so:

```html
<div class="name" data-name="Joey">Joey</div>
```

```html
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.name');
var input= document.querySelector('input.search-box-selector');

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        var name = elements[i].dataset.name;
        //check strings against each other
    }
```

With the example provided you *could* get the innerHTML of the element and check that, but that is not a very flexible solution. Let's say you then get a feature request to additionally sort the results by age? Or score? or favourite colour? or all the above? Yikes!

This will be much easier to implement with data-* attributes, which is why I always always always recommend them to anyone looking to read information from the DOM in js. It makes your code more flexible.

Comment: I did not read the question correctly the first time. I have updated the answer to better fit the question. I would still recommend using the data-* attribute for reasons stated in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little fiddle I prepared using the jquery autocomplete UI:

```js
$( function() {
    var availableTags = $.makeArray($('div.names').map((i,d)=>$(d).text()));
    $( "#Search" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  } );
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="Search" placeholder="placeholder text" autofocus>
<div class="names">Joey</div>
<div class="names">Alec</div>
<div class="names">Mike</div>
<div class="names">Fred</div>
<div class="names">George</div>
<div class="names">Anne</div>
<div class="names">Cordelia</div>
<div class="names">Jenny</div>
<div class="names">Melanie</div>
```